# Add column to datatable and populate with query against same datatable in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable with five columns. I want to create a new column that contains the difference between two datetime fields for all rows.

The datatable, dtb, was originally populated from a sql server database.
Current columns are: ID, startDate, codeID, Param, and endTime.
The new column will be a duration that is the difference between endTime and startDate.
The difference should be down to less than seconds, so if this can be done through sql I assume datediff with milliseconds parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select ID, startDate, codeID, Param, endTime, DateDiff(ms,endTime,startDate) As yourdiff from dtb` that will be your query. Do you want to alter the table?

Comment: That works good assuming the difference isn't so great that it causes an OverFlow.

Comment: That's true "For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds." from msdn. @NoAlias so is there a way to do the diff beyond this range with milli seconds?

Comment: Good question.  In .Net it shouldn't be a problem, but SQL is the ideal place for this change.

Comment: Is it possible to add the column to the datatable without affecting the table in the actual database?
Yes that's the query I want, the question was really directed toward how it is implemented in vb and creating the new column in the datatable.

Comment: You don't have to add a new column to your datatable, add your query to data adapter and fill your datatable with data adapter, it should get the column. let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: @scc endTime field was populated in same way and I'm not sure how to use it as a param in datediff now. My datatable was populated using:  `Select ID, startDate, codeID, Param, (select top 1 startDate from myTable where ID='" & ID & "' and Param = mt.param and codeID = 82 and startDate >= '" & startDate & "' and startDate >=mt.startDate ORDER BY startDate)endTime, from myTable mt where ID = '" & ID & "' AND (startDate between '" & startDate & "' AND '" & endDate & "' AND (codeID = 81))`